# Determine signal frequency

Tags: matlab

I am trying to determine the frequency of a signal given as a vector in Matlab.
Any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `fft()` function in Matlab.

This contains both the phase and amplitude, to get the amplitude only you can use `abs(fft(..))`

Comment: Doh, I was so close. Thanks VoodooChild!