# Find value of frequency form Sin wav

Tags: matlab, wav

i have a this following equation of sine wav

```
Fs = 8000; % Sampling rate of signal
Fc = 3000; % Carrier frequency
t = [0:Fs-1]'/Fs; % Sampling times
dev = 50; % Frequency deviation in modulated signal

s1 = sin(2*pi*200*t)+2*sin(2*pi*f*t);
```

now i want to value of ***f*** for **s1** equation how can we get this? thanks

Comment: Question is not clear: do you want to modulate a signal using frequency modulation? Or do you want to determine a frequency given a measured signal? And is `f` the same as `Fc`?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "f". The above code would return an error since f is not defined. You can always perform an fft and find the maxima in the spectrum to determine frequencies in a signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look around SO for [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112672/determine-signal-frequency/3112721#3112721) questions.

The FFT is the simplest route to a solution:

```
spec = abs(fft(s1));
```

Then search for the maxima in the spectrum using a detection threshold.

Example (here `f=10`):

```
f= 10;
s1 = sin(2*pi*200*t)+2*sin(2*pi*f*t);

thresh = 0.2;
f1=abs(fft(s1))/sum(abs(s1));
f= [0:length(f1)-1]/length(f1)*Fs;
f(f1(1:end/2)>0.2)
```

This is the result (the frequencies in the spectrum for peaks with amplitude greater than the threshold value):

```
ans =

    10   200
```

Comment: thanks for answer i want only value of f that is 10 in your example because i want to compare it with other sin wav frequency? only f value?

Comment: i got it by this                                                                   Fs = 8000; % Sampling rate of signal                               Fc = 3000; % Carrier frequency
t = [0:Fs-1]'/Fs; % Sampling times
f= 10;
s1 = sin(2*pi*200*t)+2*sin(2*pi*f*t);
thresh = 0.2;
f1=abs(fft(s1))/sum(abs(s1));
f= [0:length(f1)-1]/length(f1)*Fs;
dd= f(f1(1:end/2)>0.2);
dd
dd(1:end,1)                                                        dd =

    10   200


ans =

    10

Comment: @user2322360 I'm a little confused about your question. Please see how I modified the answer, hopefully this makes everything clear. I used a specific value of "f" as an example. The idea is that, if f is unknown, by following a similar method to the one I posted you can determine the unknown value of f.

Comment: i have value of 'f' of a sin wav already i want to compare the other sin wav to my sin wav in switch butt in switch it is not possible to compare a sin wav to other finaly only one way is that compare values of 'f' of both sin wavs to make decision. so thats y i get the value of 'f'.