# How to Compare two Chanel s in Matlab

Tags: matlab, wav

i have two chanels s1 and s2 how can we compare s1 and s2 to test in matlab both are equal or not?

```
s1 = sin(2*pi*2*t)+2*sin(2*pi*f1*t); % Channel 1
s2 = sin(2*pi*4*t)+2*sin(2*pi*f2*t); % Channel 2
```

how can we do this?

Comment: Please don't post a lot of similar questions in a row. Ask one question at a time and edit the question if you want to change something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have defined `s1` and `s2`, it is not possible for the signals to be equal.

Should you still want to test with matlab, however, and assuming you know nothing *a priori* about the signals, FFT both (as explained in my answer to your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672158/find-value-of-frequency-form-sin-wav)), and compare the frequency **and** amplitude of the peaks (and if you wish, phase).